# Powershell: How to download the latest file from a DropBox Folder?

Tags: powershell, download, dropbox

I need to be able to create a Powershell script, that will download the latest file from a folder in DropBox. Each day it will need to run to get the very latest file. Currently, there are hundreds of files in the folder, so I just need to download one file.

I can get connected to Dropbox with my script.

Any help will be appreciated.

I have tried a script that will download the entire folder, but that times out since there are so many files in the folder.

Comment: You could use `Invoke-WebRequest` to download information about the folder contents and parse out the file name you need,  and then again `Invoke-WebRequest` to download file.

Comment: I have tested that. It does not find the newest file.

Comment: I suppose link to dropbox is private ex. tied to your user account, and also it's difficult to say why `Invoke-WebRequest` doesn't work without seeing problem code and test link to online directory. see also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I need to know how to download a single file in a DropBox folder. I can use the Invoke-WebRequst function. Can someone provide a script for this?

Comment: I don't want to be rude but stack overflow is about solving problems with code, not about writing complete code for somebody else, please update your question with the code you have written so far and point out issues with it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to do this:

wget -Uri https://www.dropbox.com/home/FolderName/$Filename?dl=1 -d -OutFile "c:\temp$FileName" -Verbose